# Contact Form: parse error

Tags: php, forms

I can't see what's my mistake. I have to put some text. I have too much code?
I'm little stressed by this problem. I'm a beginner and I'm working too hard perhaps.

```
<?php

    $n = array();

    if (!empty($_POST))
    {
        extract($_POST);
        $valid = true;

        if (empty($nom))
        {
            $valid = false;
            $erreur = 'Erreur nom';
            $n['erreurnom'] = true;
        }

        if (empty($email))
        {
            $valid = false;
            $erreur = 'Erreur email';
            $n['emailinvalide'] = false;
            $n['erreuremail'] = true;
        }
        elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-_.]+@[a-z0-9\-_.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/i', $email))
        {
            $valid = false;
            $erreur = 'Votre email n\'est pas valide';
            $n['erreuremail'] = false;
            $n['emailinvalide'] = true;
        }

        if (empty($message))
        {
            $valid = false;
            $erreur = 'Erreur message';
            $n['erreurmessage'] = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $valid = false;
    }   
    $n['valide'] = $valid;
    echo json_encode($n);


    if ($valid = true)
    {
        $to = 'lalala@monmail.fr<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    (function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){})();
    /* ]]> */
    </script>';
        $sujet = $nom . ' a contacté le site';
        $header = 'From: $nom <$email> \n';
        $message = stripslashes($message);
        $nom = stripslashes($nom);

        if (mail($to, $sujet, $message, $header))
        {
            $erreur = 'Votre email nous est bien parvenu';
        }
        else
        {
            $erreur = 'Une erreur est survenue. Mail bloqué';
        }
        echo $erreur;
    }
?>
```

My problem: `parse error in "(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script") ....."`

Comment: Don't use `extract()`! It is very unsafe.

Comment: There's an unescaped `'` inside your string which the parser interprets as its end.

Comment: Why on earth have you got javascript embedded in your email `$to` variable????

Comment: See, that's why you don't put 345 chars on one single line, especially when they contain logic that you would otherwise spread over multiple lines anyways. Now write your lambda in a readable way and find your error. In addition, any decent IDE will tell you where to look for the error. And also, what @Spudley said.

Comment: extract ist unsafe??? But it's only for safety i used extract lol (it's a advice we gave me)... ok i'll change that. For the ' i don't see it.

Comment: @gordon: i know... but i had help and just a copy paste of the code (which i don't understand anyway ^^ i don't know what it makes)

Comment: @Bondye `extract()` is only unsafe when it is used with the default `EXTR_OVERWRITE` in a scope where it can potentially overwrite existing variables.

Comment: $to = 'lalala@monmail.fr<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){
 try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");
 l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;
 a=l.getAttribute("data-cfemail");
 if(a){
  s="";r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);
  for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){
   c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;
   s+=String.fromCharCode(c);
   }
  s=document.createTextNode(s);
  l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);
  }
 }catch(e){
  })
 ();
/* ]]> */
</script>';

I have replace ' by " in some data... well see

Comment: @Gordon Anyway using `extract()` is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: So it's fonctionning but it does send nothing... lol

I'm doomed lol... when i erase that js part, everything is ok!

SB have documentation about this js part? I don't understand it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'[...]previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute(('data-cfemail')[...]'
                                        ^            ^
                                        here         and here
```

You use a `'` in a string which was opened with `'`, you have to escape it to `\'`, like that:

```
'[...]previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute((\'data-cfemail\')[...]'
```

Comment: Thanx!But now all my ajax/js on index (with the form) doesn't work anymore lol... i must search...

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the content of :

```
getAttribute('data-cfemail');
```

by adding slashes

```
getAttribute(\'data-cfemail\');
```